# There is a logical error in my code, I can't fix my code to print the divisor in center and also the user's prompt

Tags: c

I've encountered a logical error in my code related to the printing of divisors,
and I'm struggling to identify the issue. Additionally,
when the user provides an invalid input in the initial prompts,
the program reprints the message, but the alignment is not centered.
Could you please assist me   in addressing these issues?
Below is the relevant code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 
 #define winWid 160
 #define Red "\033[0;31m"
 #define Reset "\033[0m"

 int num;

 // Function to print text centered on the screen
 void print(const char *text)
 {
    int len = strlen(text);
    int padd = (winWid - len) / 2;
    printf("%*s%s", padd, "", text);
 }

 // Function to print text centered on the screen with a numerical value
 void Nprint(const char *let, int value)
 {
    int length = strlen(let);
    int padding = (winWid - length) / 2;
    printf("%*s", padding, "");
    printf(let, value);
 }

 // Function to print an error message in red
 void error(const char *mssg)
 {
    printf(Red);
    print(mssg);
    printf(Reset "\n");
 }
 
 // Function to get a valid user input within a specified range
int valid(const char *inpType, int min)
{
char userInp[50]; // Buffer to store user input
int result; // Variable to store the converted user input

 while (1) // Infinite loop until valid input is received
 {
    printf("%s", inpType); // Print the input prompt

    // Read user input from the standard input (keyboard)
    if (fgets(userInp, sizeof(userInp), stdin) == NULL)
    {
        error("Invalid input! Please enter a number.");
        continue; // Continue the loop if reading input fails
    }

    userInp[strcspn(userInp, "\n")] = 0; // Remove the newline character

    if (!validInp(userInp)) // Check if input is a valid integer
    {
        error("Invalid input! Please enter a number only.");
        continue; // Continue the loop if input is not a valid integer
    }

    result = atoi(userInp); // Convert the user input to an integer

    if (result < min) // Check if the input is less than the specified minimum
    {
        error("Invalid input! Please enter a positive number.");
        continue; // Continue the loop if input is less than the minimum
    }

    break; // Break out of the loop when valid input is obtained
 }

 return result; // Return the valid user input
 }

 // Function to check if a number is perfect and print its divisors
int inpNum(int div)
{
int sum = 0; // Variable to store the sum of divisors

// Print the header for displaying divisors
Nprint("Divisors of %d: 1", div);

// Iterate through potential divisors starting from 2 up to half of the number
for (int i = 2; i <= div / 2; i++)
{
    if (div % i == 0) // Check if the current number is a divisor
    {
        sum += i; // Add the divisor to the sum
        Nprint(", %d", i); // Print the divisor
    }
}

printf("\n"); // Move to a new line for better formatting

/*Return true if the sum of divisors plus 1 equals the original 
number, indicating a perfect    number*/
return sum + 1 == div;
}
 
   // Main function to execute the Perfect or Not number program
   void PoN()
   {
     system("cls"); //clearing the console
     print("|===========================================|\n");
     print("|       Perfect or not number program       |\n");
     print("|===========================================|\n");

     int messageLength = strlen("Please enter a number: ");
     int padd = (winWid - messageLength) / 2;
     printf("%*s", padd, "");
  
     num = valid("Please enter a number: ", 0);

     if (inpNum(num))
     {
       Nprint("\n%d is a perfect number!\n", num);
     }
     else
     {
        Nprint("\n%d is not a perfect number!\n", num);
     }
   }

   // Entry point of the program
   int main()
   {
     PoN();// calling the PoN void
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you expect others to read it. This looks really sloppy.

Comment: Note that helpfully minded users might perceive this as two questions in one post. If possible try to focus this on only one of them, along with a [mre] focusing on it and demosntrating it. That also should include that you provide the output in contrast to the expected output, and/or a detailed description of any other symptom. The input validation issue seems to be the easier one to separate and focus on first - also however the more likely one to find already covered by other existing Q/A pairs here.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to test and troubleshoot your code, the first thing that needed to be done was add a placeholder function definition for "validInp" as the compiler complained about that not being defined.

```
main.c|| undefined reference to `validInp'|
```

After adding in a placeholder function, the main point of focus was when and where to add space padding in regard to prompting for an input value and when to utilize the "Nprint" function and when to utilize standard string functions to construct the list of divisors for the perfect number testing.

Running a test with the value "496" resulted in what you probably are experiencing with the unwanted spacing of the divisors when utilizing the "Nprint" function.

```
       |===========================================|
       |       Perfect or not number program       |
       |===========================================|
                  Please enter a number: 496
                     Divisors of 496: 1                            , 2                            , 4                            , 8                            , 16                            , 31                            , 62                            , 124                            , 248
                 
496 is a perfect number!
```

That function does work for the final determination text, but not so well for printing the divisors.  This is where one probably would want to utilize standard string functions such as "strcat" and "sprintf".  With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define winWid 60
#define Red "\033[0;31m"
#define Reset "\033[0m"

int num;

int validInp(char *text)
{
    /* Just to get this program to work - left out of the code example */

    return 1;
}

// Function to print text centered on the screen
void print(const char *text)
{
    int len = strlen(text);
    int padd = (winWid - len) / 2;
    printf("%*s%s", padd, "", text);
}

// Function to print text centered on the screen with a numerical value
void Nprint(const char *let, int value)
{
    int length = strlen(let);
    int padding = (winWid - length) / 2;
    printf("\n%*s", padding, "");
    printf(let, value);
}

// Function to print an error message in red
void error(const char *mssg)
{
    printf(Red);
    print(mssg);
    printf(Reset "\n");
}

// Function to get a valid user input within a specified range
int valid(const char *inpType, int min)
{
    char userInp[50];                       // Buffer to store user input
    int result;                             // Variable to store the converted user input
    int messageLength = strlen(inpType);    /* Moved the padding setup into the function    */
    int padd = (winWid - messageLength) / 2;

    while (1)                               // Infinite loop until valid input is received
    {
        printf("%*s", padd, "");
        printf("%s", inpType); // Print the input prompt

        // Read user input from the standard input (keyboard)
        if (fgets(userInp, sizeof(userInp), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            error("Invalid input! Please enter a number.");
            continue; // Continue the loop if reading input fails
        }

        userInp[strcspn(userInp, "\n")] = 0; // Remove the newline character

        if (!validInp(userInp)) // Check if input is a valid integer
        {
            error("Invalid input! Please enter a number only.");
            continue; // Continue the loop if input is not a valid integer
        }

        result = atoi(userInp); // Convert the user input to an integer

        if (result < min) // Check if the input is less than the specified minimum
        {
            error("Invalid input! Please enter a positive number.");
            continue; // Continue the loop if input is less than the minimum
        }

        break; // Break out of the loop when valid input is obtained
    }

    return result; // Return the valid user input
}

// Function to check if a number is perfect and print its divisors
int inpNum(int div)
{
    int sum = 0; // Variable to store the sum of divisors
    char text[80];
    char work[80];

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        text[i] = '\0';

// Print the header for displaying divisors
    strcat(text, "Divisors of ");
    sprintf(work, "%d", div);
    strcat(text, work);

// Iterate through potential divisors starting from 2 up to half of the number
    for (int i = 2; i <= div / 2; i++)
    {
        if (div % i == 0) // Check if the current number is a divisor
        {
            sum += i; // Add the divisor to the sum
            sprintf(work, ", %d", i);                   /* In lieu of Nprint    */
            strcat(text, work);
        }
    }

    int messageLength = strlen(text);
    int padd = (winWid - messageLength) / 2;

    if (padd < 0)
        padd = 0;

    printf("\n%*s", padd, "");                          /* In lieu of Nprint    */
    printf("%s\n", text);

    /*Return true if the sum of divisors plus 1 equals the original
    number, indicating a perfect    number*/
    return (sum + 1 == div);
}

// Main function to execute the Perfect or Not number program
void PoN()
{
    system("clear"); //clearing the console             /* Running on a Linux system    */
    print("|===========================================|\n");
    print("|       Perfect or not number program       |\n");
    print("|===========================================|\n");

    num = valid("Please enter a number: ", 0);

    if (inpNum(num))
    {
        Nprint("%d is a perfect number!\n", num);
    }
    else
    {
        Nprint("%d is not a perfect number!\n", num);
    }
}

// Entry point of the program
int main()
{
    PoN();// calling the PoN void
    return 0;
}
```

My apologies for including the full code as the refactoring occurred throughout the program.  Following are the key bits to note.

- As noted, a placeholder block of code was added for the "validInp" function so as to get the program to compile and function (your actual function will need to be added).
- To get any repeated prompting of a valid input, the setup of padding and prompting text was moved into the "valid" function.
- In lieu of utilizing the "Nprint" function for printing each of the divisors, the standard "sprintf" and "strcat" functions are used to build a aesthetically nicer text with the list of divisors.

Also, you can note the additional comments as to the purpose of some of the refactoring.  FYI, for aesthetics on my system, I revised the window width to "60" to make the output more presentable in this answer.

Following was a retest with the refactored code.

```
       |===========================================|
       |       Perfect or not number program       |
       |===========================================|
                  Please enter a number: 496

       Divisors of 496, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248

                  496 is a perfect number!
```

The main take-aways are probably to delve some more into "C" tutorials, especially as it pertains to character arrays (strings) and their supporting functions to provide simpler formatting functionality.